# robotframework table based testing

Tags: robotframework

I have a JSON file which I would like to test values. There are about 10 different values I would like to test so writing each test would be cumbersome.

I have something like this

```
Test
${json} | Get File | foo.json
${object}= | Evaluate | json.loads('''${json}''') | json
Should Be Equal | ${object['key']} | bar
```

Instead of writing 10 of these statements, is it possible for me to  create a table of tests and execute against that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use test [template](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates) to avoid writing the statement multiple times. Then i suppouse it depends whether or not each statement is testcase for you or if all 10 are just one testcase.
This code will execute the keyword and you will have 10 different testcases.

```
***Settings***
Test Template    Foo
***Variables***
${json}             {"foo": "2.0","bar": 0,"baz": "1"}
*** Test Cases ***
Fitrst Test    foo    2.0
Second Test    bar    ${0}
Third Test    baz    1

***Keywords***
Foo
    [Tags]    test
    [Arguments]    ${key}    ${expected_result}
    ${object}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${json}''')    json
    Should Be Equal    ${object}[${key}]    ${expected_result}
```

There is also a [data driver](https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver) extension for robot framework, but i have no experience with it. You will have to find on your own